# Business validation in mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, xml-validation, mule-component

I want to do field level validation in mule, i am able do the schema  validation but stuck in field level validation for example first name should be string and not empty and date of birth  should in be in integer format and not empty etc..

I am attaching my sample file , i know there is a component ( validation) which do such type of validation but i have many filed in XML ( here i have attached simple XML file due to security issues),which is basically called business validation.

Kindly help  me how to do such type of validation in mule.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:books xmlns:x="urn:books">
   <book id="bk001">
      <author>Writer</author>
      <title>The First Book</title>
      <genre>Fiction</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <pub_date>2000-10-01</pub_date>
      <review>An amazing story of nothing.</review>
   </book>

   <book id="bk002">
      <author>Poet</author>
      <title>The Poet's First Poem</title>
      <genre>Poem</genre>
      <price>24.95</price>
      <review>Least poetic poems.</review>
   </book>
</x:books>
```

Cheers,
Isr

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to below link. you can use validations module i has predefined set of validations.
**https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/validations-module**

```
EX: To validate a field is not empty. use this validator module.
     <validation:is-not-empty expression="#[(xpath expression goes here)/]" />
```

If it doesn't match your expectations then using Xpath parse the respective fields and use an expression component to do all these validations.
Thanks!